# VS2010 Performance Profiling Problem (PRF0017: Can't launch server for ..)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling

I have 2 websites running my local IIS 7.5

One is a publicportal and the other one is a service website that is the application end of the publicportal

There's no problem profiling the publicportal but when I add the application website as a profiling target it say's PRF0017: Can't launch server for 'http://localhost/adman/

I tried adding a default page to it but the same error keeps coming up.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this error yesterday and somehow stumbled on the solution:

Selecting the "IntelliTrace events and call information" radio button option under 
**Tools-->Options-->IntelliTrace-->General**

[image: screen shot of tools_options]

causes the following error when attempting to run a performance profile session.  This prevents the performance profile session from starting.

[image: screen shot of Error Encountered]

In order to run a performance profile successfully, you must select "IntelliTrace events only"

[image: screen shot of correct IntelliTrace option]

Comment: I seem not to have this option, which version / Edition of Visual Studio are you using?